# npm global truffle install error

Tags: truffle, nodejs, ganache, npm

I just got Node Js and npm yesterday and I'm new to this. When I try to install Truffle I get this error:

```
C:\Users\chris>npm install -g truffle
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp-promise@5.0.1: This package is broken and no longer maintained. 'mkdirp' itself supports promises now, please switch to that.
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated multicodec@1.0.4: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated uuid@2.0.1: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated multibase@0.6.1: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated multibase@0.7.0: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.2.1: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.2.1: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.3.2: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated multicodec@0.5.7: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated node-pre-gyp@0.11.0: Please upgrade to @mapbox/node-pre-gyp: the non-scoped node-pre-gyp package is deprecated and only the @mapbox scoped package will recieve updates in the future
npm WARN deprecated cids@0.7.5: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module

added 302 packages, changed 553 packages, and audited 885 packages in 3m

107 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

9 moderate severity vulnerabilities

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

Comment: They are not errors but warnings. They are warning you that those packages are outdated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no error in this log, only warnings about deprecated package versions. You can use the provided `npm audit fix` to fix the ones which can be fixed automatically